# Скрипт не меняет класс при клике

Tags: php, javascript

Приветствую всех, подскажите где может быть ошибка, не меняется класс на актив при нажатии кнопок, получается выделена всегда кнопка "обзор". В чем может быть ошибка

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul id="menuHead">
    <li>
      <a href="/news" target="_top" class="newmessage">Новости</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/profile" target="_top">Обзор</a>
    </li>
    <?
      $usid=$ _SESSION[ "user_id"]; 
      $db->Query("SELECT * FROM ".$pref."_pm WHERE user_id_in = '$usid' AND status = 0 AND inbox = 1");
      $sk = $db->NumRows();
      if ($sk > 0) {
        $pmm = '<font color="red">('.$sk.')</font>';
      } else {
        $pmm = '<font color="red">(0)</font>';
      }
    ?>
    <li>
      <a href="/msg" target="_top" id="msgmenu">Сообщения <?=$pmm; ?></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/hideout" target="_top">Пещера</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/city" target="_top">Город</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/robbery" target="_top">Охота</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/stats" target="_top">ТОП-лист</a>
    </li>

    <li class="free-space ">
      <a href="/contats" target="_blank">Поддержка</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/logout" target="_top">Выйти из игры</a>
    </li>
    <li id="doc_time">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        clock();
      </script>
    </li>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      var currentPage = $('#menuHead .active').text();
      $('#header h1').text(currentPage);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menuHead li').live('click', function() {
          $('#menuHead .active').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: какая версия jquery используется? функция live - устарела в 1.7 и удалена в 1.9

Comment: стоит jquery.1.4.4

Comment: ошибка в том. что происходит редирект при клике на `a` и так как на всех страницах одно и то же меню, а active устанавливается только один раз в разметке - то после редиректа _получается выделена всегда кнопка "обзор"_

Answer (score 1):

```js
var currentPage = $('#menuHead .active').text();
$('#header h1').text(currentPage);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menuHead a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var $this = $(this),
        item = $(this).closest('li');
    
    if(!item.hasClass('active')){
      item.addClass('active')
          .siblings()
          .removeClass('active');
    }else {
      item.removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* для наглядности */
.active {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<div id="menu">
  <ul id="menuHead">
    <li>
      <a href="/news" target="_top" class="newmessage">Новости</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="/profile" target="_top">Обзор</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/msg" target="_top" id="msgmenu">Сообщения <?=$pmm; ?></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/hideout" target="_top">Пещера</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/city" target="_top">Город</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/robbery" target="_top">Охота</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/stats" target="_top">ТОП-лист</a>
    </li>

    <li class="free-space ">
      <a href="/contats" target="_blank">Поддержка</a> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/logout" target="_top">Выйти из игры</a>
    </li>
    <li id="doc_time">
      
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: чем отличается от соседнего ответа?

Comment: _Uncaught ReferenceError: clock is not defined_

Comment: @Grundy, отличается тем, что работает! clock левая функция - логично что ошибку выдает!

Comment: Раз выдает ошибку - уже не работает. Плюс изменена логика выделения по сравнению с исходной, плюс сломаны переходы к другим страницам

Comment: по сути, что тут, что в соседнем ответе один и тот же способ - `e.preventDefault()` только тут клики только на `a` ловятся что еще раз меняет исходное поведение

Comment: Ну я уже написал, что ты сломала логику выделения, и скопировала решение с соседнего ответа :) И вы оба - ломали поведение на сайте :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentPage = $('#menuHead .active').text();
  $('#header h1').text(currentPage);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menuHead').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#menuHead .active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: это не сработает, потому что preventDefault нужно делать на элементе `a` а не `li`. Не говоря уже о том, что если ожидается редирект на другую страницу - запрещать его и оставаться на той же где и были - фактически означает - сломать логику

Comment: @Grundy, `preventDefault` можно делать в любой момент же. Главное, чтобы это было то же событие и его обработчик. А вот что переход исчезнет - согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, действительно, почему-то всегда думал, что наоборот :)

Answer (score 0):

Переход на страницу не стопорится потеряли `return false` и переход получается с обновлением всей страницы, а js так не умеет сохраняться, он может сохраняться до перезагрузки страницы, чтобы и это избежать, придется сделать на сервере, а для этого нужно сделать условие на каждую `li`.

```
<?php
   $url = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:'';
?>
<li class="<?='/news'===$url?'active':''?>">
```

Ну думаю как заметили - это как минимум в ручную проставлять, так делать не есть гуд, но это ваше решение.

Советую смотреть в эту сторону:

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    'news' => array('Новости'),
    'profile' => array('Профиль'),
    'disableLink' => array('Выключенная кнопка', false)
);

function menu(array $array) {
    $menu = '';
    if ($array) {
        $url = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page');
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $class = isset($value[1]) && is_bool($value[1]) && !$value[1] ? 'disable' : '';
            if (!$class) {
                if ($url === $key) {
                    $class = 'active';
                    $key = '#';
                }
            }
            $class = $class ? ' class="' . $class . '"' : '';
            $menu .= '<li' . $class . '>
                        <a href="' . $key . '">
                            ' . $value[0] . '
                        </a>
                    </li>';
        }
    }
    return $menu;
}
?>

<ul>
    <?= menu($pages) ?>
</ul>
```